# Is there a way in Flutter to catch the "start-moving" event in a Dismissible Widget?

Tags: flutter

I am using the Dismissible widget to be able to remove certain screens/widgets from a flutter app by swiping them up.

What I need to achieve is to blur the image once the user starts swiping/dismissing them but the widget only has the "onDismissed" callback, but does not offer a way to catch the swiping event.

Any alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve That using the GestureDetector widget

```
// This is the sample
GestureDetector(onPanUpdate: (details) {
  if (details.delta.dx > 0) {
    // swiping in right direction
  }
});
```

You can check there are many events that you can trigger like onHorizontalDragUpdate, and many more you can check out.

Comment: I tried wrapping my widgets: 
Dismissible( GestureDetector ( MyWidget()) 

and also   GestureDetector( Dismissible( MyWidget)))
and none of them worked. "onPanUpdate" was never being called

Comment: Can you add Some code that I go through, And based on it I can make a sample example for you,